# How to compare a string from a query results?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to get the total number of records that a column has for a string.

For example, `seller` column = 'ONA'. I want to know how many records are equal to "ONA" and how many are not.

This is what I have:

```
<cfset stringONA= "ONA">
<CFSET onaseller= 0>
<CFSET notseller=0>

<cfloop query="getunion_again">
  <cfif #getunion_again.seller# eq stringONA>
    <cfset onaseller = onaseller +1 >
    <P>TEST</P>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset notseller = notseller +1>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var=#onaseller #>
<cfdump var=#notseller #>
```

I'm not getting any errors, just not getting any count.

Comment: How many records are in your query? Both variables being 0 indicates your query has no records

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `<cfdump var=#onaseller#>
<cfdump var=#notseller#>` without those spaces before `#`?

Comment: @user3558931 : Although not having a space is a good coding practice, but won't give any error in this case.

Comment: And what troubleshooting have you done to try to work out why your code doesn't work the way you expect it to?

Comment: You need to provide more information about what troubleshooting steps you have performed so far. 1) Are *both* counts zero OR only one of them? 2) Did you dump the `getunion_again` query and verify it is not empty AND that "seller" actually contains anything like "ONA"? 3) Leading or trailing white space in the value would prevent a match. Did you check the length of the "seller" value within your loop? Also, what is the data type of the `seller` column? If it is a non-variable `char` the value might not match due to padding, unless you trim() it.

Comment: @AdamCameron - Haha, beat me in both timing and brevity ;-)

Comment: @Leigh, TBH mate, I'm losing the will to live with how often I/we need to repeat the same bloody requests on 80% of the questions asked on this site. So I'm getting more and more terse about it.

Comment: @AdamCameron - I am normally a pretty patient person, but after reading the recent comments beneath one of your other answers ... well, you are about to have company on that ledge ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be easier to do a query-of-query to get the number of records that match your criteria without looping?

```
<cfquery name="qryCount" dbtype="query">
SELECT COUNT(*) AS positive_count
FROM getunion_again
WHERE seller = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#stringONA#">
</cfquery>

<cfset onaseller = qryCount.positive_count>
<cfset notseller = getunion_again.recordcount - onaseller>
```

Comment: @user3591637: I have to contest that this is the best answer here, I'm afraid. QoQ has quite a large processing overhead and simply isn't needed here. It's definitely *an* answer, but it's not the approach you should take.

Answer (score 3):

One can use [`listValueCountNoCase()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListValueCountNoCase) to count the matches in a list, and one can use [`valueList()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/valueList) to extract a query column as a list. And the number of mismatches is the number of rows less the number of matches.

So:

```
values = valueList(getunion_again.seller);
onaseller = listValueCountNoCase(values, stringONA);
notseller = getunion_again.recordCount - onaseller;
```

Comment: Not sure if it applies here, but if you *only* need the total counts, I would recommend a db query and `CASE` statement instead.